# How can we write Chunks of data for a Huge List of Custom Objects using ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java

I'm writing a huge list of Custom Objects using ObjectOutputStream in Java
and the code snippet is as below and my question is on the usage of ObjectOutputStream
Should I use **BufferedOutputStream** instead of **ObjectOutPutStream** to increase the performance of write operation in a loop ? Or **is there a way to write to ObjectOutputStream using chunk of data and how can I call flush() inside the for loop** ?
Thanks for your time

```
protected void writeTransferObject(List<? extends DataTransfer> dataTransferList,
        HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(response.getOutputStream()))
        {
            for ( DataTransfer dataTransfer : dataTransferList)
            {
                oos.writeObject(dataTransfer);
               
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you can increase the performance, when you using a `Stream` instead of a `List`. A `List` with all it's objects are in RAM at the same time - if you are running low on RAM, then the OS starting to swap out memory, which needs a lot of CPU-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, to your performance question: Java is always going to run faster than the writing to disk, so there isn't much point in optimizing in Java.

Second: Input/Output buffers: These are only necessary for doing *inefficient* reading/writing: For example on the read side, reading line by line rather than just gobbling bytes, and on the write side writing scraps of things from multiple places before sending it out as one I/O op.

Third: ObjectOutputStream:  I strongly recommend against using ObjectOutputStream (and DataOutputStream), and recommend Jackson/JSON or XML as an alternative. ObjectOutputStream is Java-only, depends on all serialized Objects to implement Serializable sensibly, and is *very* sensitive to changes in class definition.

Comment: And it opens a wide door for attackers. Just google for "java exploit serializable class" and you will find plenty of explanations.